# How to convert String to VariableBinding ? (org.snmp4j.mp.SnmpConstants)

Tags: java, snmp, snmp4j

I am trying to write a function which makes a snmp query. I am getting all parameters from a config file so I want to convert String to VariableBinding to use as a variable parameter in Set function ?
Do you know how to do it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A variable binding can be constructed using an object identifier (such as 1.3.6.1.1.1.0) and an SNMP object, such as OctetString.

http://www.snmp4j.org/doc/org/snmp4j/smi/OctetString.html

Make sure you understand SNMP concepts first, and then you will find the API kind of familiar.